# Unauthorized to get _api/contextinfo from a Sharepoint domain with POSTMAN Forbidden reason

Tags: sharepoint, postman

Starting from two **Sharepoint** domains, say **accessible.sharepoint.com** and **unaccesible.sharepoint.com**, from **POSTMAN**, we are able to access **_api/contextinfo** in the first case (**200 OK**), but not in the second (**403 Forbidden**).

In concrete:

**`{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."}}}`**

Could someone tell me what actions I have to ask the technicians who control the **unaccesible.sharepoint.com** domain to carry out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't it look like they just need to grant you access to the unacessible sharepoint site?

Comment: I dont know, because we are able to connect with this python script: https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we are able to do that, connecting to site level:
https://unaccesible.sharepoint.com/sites/<our_site>/_api/contextinfo